# Binding viewModel property with variable

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel

**Intro:** 
I need to call the backend controller to see if the user is admin. If the user is **NOT** admin, hide the toolbar in the application. Currently the var is successfully changing; However, it is changing after the view is already created causing the view to always have the toolbar visable.

**Problem:**

- Need to check backend to see if user is in the admin group.
- Need to return true if they are in admin group

**MyCode:**

```
var adminBool = false;

function CheckAdmin() {
    debugger;
    var a;
    Direct.Report.IsAdmin(this.results, a);
    debugger;
};

function results(result, constructor, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
    debugger;
    this.adminBool= result.adminUser; //returns bool
}

Ext.define('Ext.View.MyViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    alias: 'viewmodel.AdministrationViewModel',
    init: this.CheckAdmin(),
    data: {
        addNew: true,
        update: true,
        gridData: null,
        isAdmin: this.adminBool
    }
});
```

**Synopsis:**

1. Call the backend controller for admin status
2. Return bool
3. Update viewModel with bool respectively
4. ViewModel property,'isAdmin', will bind with hidden property to hide unwanted actions for non admins

**UPDATE:**

Basically I need a way to delay "isAdmin: this.adminBool" check to after the backend call is finished.

Comment: does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Not the best solution, but why don't you start with your `unwanted actions` component hidden? Meanwhile your ext direct asynchronous request will validate the login  and change your `isAdmin` to true (if the case), therefore showing the hidden component.

Comment: So I do have this as you mentioned, however when the isAdmin becomes true it does not change update the program to unhide the toolbar.

Comment: Did you set `bind: { hidden: '{!isAdmin}' }` in the component you want to hide if not admin?

Comment: Yes I did,    bind: { hidden: '!{isAdmin}' },

Answer (score 0):

> As you are using  [ViewModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html).

So you can use [set()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-set) method to update your `viewmodel` field.

I have created an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29d6) demo using `viewmodel`. You can check, how it is working in fiddle. In this fiddle I have not used any API, it just example regarding of [ViewModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html). Hope this will help you to solve your problem or achieve your requirement.

```
//ViewModel
Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.AdministrationViewModel',
    data: {
        isAdmin: true
    }
});
//Panel
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'ViewModel example',
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    viewModel: 'AdministrationViewModel',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox', // Arrange child items vertically
        align: 'stretch', // Each takes up full width
        padding: 10
    },
    defaults: {
        margin: 10
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        height: 40,
        fieldLabel: 'Choose Admin or user',
        emptyText: 'Choose Admin or user',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'value'],
            data: [{
                "value": true,
                "name": "Admin"
            }, {
                "value": false,
                "name": "User"
            }]
        },
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'value',
        listeners: {
            select: function (combo, record) {
                var viewModel = combo.up('panel').getViewModel(),
                    isAdmin = record.get('value');

                //If selected value is {Admin} then we will show toolbar otherwise in case of {User} hide
                viewModel.set('isAdmin', !isAdmin);
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        padding: 10,
        bind: {
            hidden: '{isAdmin}'
        },
        items: [{
                // xtype: 'button', // default for Toolbars
                text: 'Admin',
            }, {
                xtype: 'splitbutton',
                text: 'Split Button'
            },
            // begin using the right-justified button container
            '->', // same as { xtype: 'tbfill' }
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'field1',
                emptyText: 'enter search term'
            },
            // add a vertical separator bar between toolbar items
            '-', // same as {xtype: 'tbseparator'} to create Ext.toolbar.Separator
            'text 1', // same as {xtype: 'tbtext', text: 'text1'} to create Ext.toolbar.TextItem
            {
                xtype: 'tbspacer'
            }, // same as ' ' to create Ext.toolbar.Spacer
            'text 2', {
                xtype: 'tbspacer',
                width: 50
            }, // add a 50px space
            'text 3'
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent doing this. 

The issue I am struggling with is to validate admin permissions on the back end. I have a function call to the back end to check and see if the user is admin, however I am sure how to make the variable to store that function return. 

My code is working properly to store the variable with the function return, however in the viewModel - "isAdmin: this.adminBool" is checking the variable before the backend call returns the value. I just need a way to delay checking "isAdmin: this.adminBool".

Comment: So in that case you can do your functionality after getting `response` of `ajax` or `backend`.

Comment: Forcing functionality after the response is my issue. Currently it is returning the response after the view renders. Only way I can think of making this work is refreshing the view, however, I think its quite dumb to refresh a view as soon as it is rendered.